# Rails Low Level cache is not caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model called Event.  In the event model, I have the following code:

```
def self.all_events
    Rails.cache.fetch("events", expires_in: 2.days) do
        Event.all.to_a
    end
end
```

I call the `all_events` method in a controller.  If the above works, then the server logs should show the query only first time the controller code is called and every time after that for the next two days the events should exist as an array in memory - right?  For some reason, the server logs show the database query every single time.  How do I make the caching work?

Comment: Are you testing this in the development env?

Comment: heroku and development. it works in neither.

Comment: What version of Rails?  Do you have this config:  `config.cache_store = :file_store, 'tmp/cache'`

Comment: in development i have `config.cache_store = :memory_store` but no line like that in production

Comment: It is ruby on rails 5

Comment: Did you inspect the /tmp/cache folder for an events file?

Comment: I assume you have `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` enabled in your environment file. Try with string interpolation, so instead of  `Rails.cache.fetch("events", expires_in: 2.days) do` , try `Rails.cache.fetch("#{events}", expires_in: 2.days) do`. The later is taken from [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching)

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure cache settings correctly in both environments.

I prefer Redis for production environment on Heroku. You can use memory_store or file_store options on development environment.
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis

Gemfile

```
gem 'redis-rails'
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :redis_store
end
```

config/environments/development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :memory_store
end
```

You can find more details for caching on Ruby on Rails on there; http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your caching configurations in both development and production. In development, you must explicitly turn on caching (with `rails dev:cache` or `touch tmp/caching-dev.txt` and restart your dev server).

Notice the caching configuration in *development.rb*,

```rb
# Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
# Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
if Rails.root.join("tmp/caching-dev.txt").exist?
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

  config.cache_store = :memory_store
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    "Cache-Control" => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
  }
else
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.cache_store = :null_store
end
```

By default, in development caching is turned off. One must explicitly turn on caching in development, per the documentation, [Caching with Rails: An Overview](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).